# Бесконечное меню

Tags: java, scanner

Здраствуйте, может кто знает, как сделать так, чтобы меню бесконечно повторялось после выполнение задания (выход с меню в 4 пункте есть). То есть пользователь нажимает 1, там выпадает подменю, он пишет текст, и когда закончил - менюшка должна появляться снова. Самый лучший вариант, который знаю - это бесконечный цикл for, может еще что есть.

```
System.out.println("Please select operation");
            System.out.println("1.Encode");
            System.out.println("2.Decode");
            System.out.println("3.View operation history");
            System.out.println("4.Exit program");
```

Comment: Вот честное слово, такой вопрос здесь задается каждый день. Понятие "поиск" вам знакомо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String  choice = "";
    do {
        System.out.println("1.Encode");
        System.out.println("2.Decode");
        System.out.println("3.View operation history");
        System.out.println("Введите номер нужного действия и нажмите <ENTER>:\n" +
            "(Для выхода из программы просто нажмите клавишу <ENTER>)");
        choice = in.nextLine();
        switch (choice) {
            case "1": System.out.println("Вы выбрали: Encode\n"); break;
            case "2": System.out.println("Вы выбрали: Decode\n"); break;
            case "3": System.out.println("Вы выбрали: View operation history\n"); break;
            default: System.out.println("Выберите один из пунктов меню, или нажмите <ENTER> " +
                "для выхода из программы\n"); break;
        }
    } while (!choice.isEmpty());
}
```

Здесь для выхода из бесконечного меню можно просто нажать ентер. Но вы можете переделать так, как вам захочется. Главное сама реализация.